# Array map not working in react native view. Text strings must be rendered within a <Text> component

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have been struggling with this code for a while now. I tried using array map to display content in react native view but keeps throwing errors which I already handled.

```js
function AppSlim() {
  //const todos = useSelector(state=>state.TodoList).list; 
  const todos = ['Hello', 'Michael']
  console.log('slim todos',todos);
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      
      <MyBtn />
      <MyModal />
      <View>
        {/* {alert("hi")} */}
        {console.log('todos',todos)}
        {todos.map((item)=>(<Text key={item}>{item}</Text>))};
        {/* <Text>Hi</Text>
        <Text>Mike</Text> */}
        
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}
```

I have been battling with this issue for quite some time and I can't see what is wrong with my code. And I get the error:

```js
Text strings must be rendered within a <Text> component.
```

What I'm I missing please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error occurs due to the semicolon after the closing curly bracket. The App tries to render the `;` as Text, but it's missing the `<Text>` Component for it.

Change this:

```
{todos.map((item)=>(<Text key={item}>{item}</Text>))};
```

To:

```
{todos.map((item)=>(<Text key={item}>{item}</Text>))}
```

**Demo:**

https://snack.expo.io/rJw5K8oL8

Answer (score 0):

try this code
Don't forget to `return` the mapped array, like:

```
 return todos.map((data) => {
          return (
            <View><Text key={item}>{item}</Text></View>
          )
        })
```

Reference for the `map()` method: [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: That's not the problem.